# In Storage security rules, how to point to a Firestore document to read user role

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I got a question about my following code to secure my firestore.
I want to allow my admin to access to every files of all users. to do that i code this function but something is not recognized by firestore. "Invalid variable name: database."
Get is also not recognized...
Could you please help me to correct this code and explain what the system give me an error ?

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  
    function isAdmin(userId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.role == "admin";
    }
    
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid);
    }
   
    match /invoices/{userId}/{soldeUid}/{fileName} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null
                   && request.auth.uid == userId
                   && soldeUid.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$")
                   && fileName.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$");
      allow read: if request.auth != null
                  && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}

many thank to all !
```

Try to position the function to the begining / to the end.
Modify the get function.

Comment: The answer below will make it work but you should instead use custom claims to manage roles, plenty of doc on this here and on Firebase

Answer (score 2):

You use **Firestore** security rules syntax in **Storage** security rules.

You can access Firestore docs in Cloud Storage security rules but the syntax is different, as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions?hl=en&authuser=0#enhance_with_firestore):

```
function isAdmin(userId) {
  return firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(userId)).role == "admin";
}
```

Comment: this function return me : Error: simulator.rules line [7], column [12]. Property role is undefined on object.
this error come from firestore.get. do you have an idea ?

Comment: Have you started all the emulators (including the Storage, Firestore and Auth one)? I would suggest you test outside of the emulator (with a deployed app) to confirm that it is a problem of emulator or not.

Comment: i already tested from a real device. i got permission denied from it. my kotlin code works fine because when i suppress the function and i allow everybody to do everythings all works well but it's unsafe to do that ...